# PHP, let user know that leave blank text field is not allow

Tags: php, mysql, web, error-handling, linker-errors

I'm changing for this website's sake...I'm trying to explain that I need something to let registrar create the register form, then if leave oe textbox blank, the click on submit, then JavaScript's alert to tell registrar to fill the blank textbox. I need this in PHP. Thank you for help in advance.

Gary

Comment: Beg your pardon? Can you make this question a bit clearer and show us your code that you have written.

Comment: All right, for example, I have 5 textfield to register. Suppose someone accidently click the button to register which is not complete all textfield, then let someone know that require to complete all textfield. I don't want to show the name of file or  something is error.

Comment: Post the code you have written within your question so that we can see specifically what you have tried, this way we are better able to understand and help you resolve this question.

Comment: All right, I can't post languages because it is too difficult to understand, but showing an image will make you understand better

Comment: Edit your question above and add the code (cut and paste).

Comment: For example, if someone leaves blank text field, then click "register" button, then it will show "Notice: Undefined index: MembersID in C:\xampp\htdocs\registeredsite.php on line 86
Column 'FirstName' cannot be null", those I don't want to have message to people, I just want to alert or next site to let user that must fill the text field before click to register.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see a javascript tag within your question. You can check to see if the text area has been set before writing the database.

```
<?php

$textArea = $_POST['textAreaName'];
$error = false;

if($_POST) {
    if(isset($textArea)) {
        // run code and write to DB
    } else {
        $error = "Please fill out text area";
    }
}

?>
```

HTML

```
<form.......>


<?php echo $error ? $error :"" ?>
<textarea></textarea>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript on the front-end, like so:

```
if(document.getElementById('InputId').value == ''){alert('fill in the blanks');}
```

You should always do a check using PHP as well:

```
if(!isset($_GET['InputId']) || empty($_GET['InputId'])){return false;}
```